# Mysql Two Tables One to many Relationships with 2 tables vs creating other relationship table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship

I have two tables

1. student(sid,sname,sage,sgender,semail)
2. Course(cid,cname,credit)

where one student can enroll for only 1 course and in one course there can be many students.
so should I use the foreign key in the course table or creating a new table for enrollment.
Is this approach depends on the situation or others?

Comment: Over time, can a student enroll in multiple courses?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current scenario, you should create foreign key in your students table similar like s_cid.

But rather I suggest create separate table for enrollment, thinking of possible future requirement change where student can attend multiple courses. So you would have enrollment table with id, sid, cid columns.